# MSBUILD complains about the null conditional operator

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have an MSBUILD project that complains about the null conditional syntax.

```
BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(parameters, BuildRequest);
```

`buildResult.ResulsByTarget`

Key: "Build"

Value: ResultCode "Failure"

My logs tell me about this error:

`Workflow\Activate.cs(283,52): error CS1525: Invalid expression term '.'`

Which when I look at the specific line in my code, it uses the null conditional operator like this

`Contract contract = Context?.Selected;`

Removing the null conditional and replacing it with null checks solves the issue but I have a lot of code using the null conditional operator. And I don't want to edit each one of them.

```
if(Context != null)
    contract = Context.Selected;
```

**UPDATE 1:**

1. I made sure that the ms build project uses the latest version of c#
2. Also made sure that the project is is trying to build has the same .net framework version

**UPDATE 2:**

Downloaded the msbuild tools for vs 2017 and used the dlls from there. However, new error occurred `The tools version "15.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "12.0", "2.0", "3.5", "4.0".`

Comment: What `MSBuild` version is used?

Comment: @UserName Before it was using 4.0, but currently 12.0 from `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin`

Comment: I think you should use the newest `MSBuild` version. The syntax from your snippet is [new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-60) to C# 6.0 and Roslyn. You can install [BuildTools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) or use `MSBuild` that shipped with Visual Studio. [Minimum compiler version needed to support all language features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/langversion-compiler-option#FCS6)

Comment: @UserName used the latest `MSBUILD`, build tools for VS 2017. Now I'm getting a new error. `The tools version "15.0" is unrecognized. Available tools versions are "12.0", "2.0", "3.5", "4.0".`

Comment: What `ToolsVersion` is used in build project? Try set to 15.0 if it  is different.